# Summing values by time intervals in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have a data series that has a start and stop timestamp and some large integer values in different columns. The goal is to sum the integer values by minute when that minute falls between start and stop.

Example

```
Record 1:
Start = 2023-12-01 00:00:22.000
Stop = 2023-12-01 00:05:20.000
Int 1 = 2384881920
Int 2 = 286304

Record 2:
Start = 2023-12-01 00:00:23.000
Stop = 2023-12-01 00:06:40.000
Int 1 = 132286544
Int 2 = 13107

Record 3:
Start = 2023-12-01 00:00:31.000
Stop = 2023-12-01 00:36:00.000
Int 1 = 6373964800
Int 2 = 533764

At 2023-12-01 00:00:22.000 my Int 1 value would be 2384881920 and Int 2 286304. At 2023-12-01 00:00:23.000 my Int 1 value would be 2384881920 + 132286544 and Int 2 286304 + 13107 because both of the records are "ongoing" at the same time. At 2023-12-01 00:00:31.000 my Int 1 value is 2384881920 + 132286544 + 6373964800 because all three of them are now "ongoing". At 2023-12-01 00:05:20.000 however, my Int 1 is now 132286544 + 6373964800 because Record 1 has reached it's stop time, but Record 2 and 3 are still "ongoing".
```

Is there a window function or some sort of conversion to unixtime and division to create rows by minute that I can then Sum across?

Initially, I tried joining the data set against itself using an interval like so.

```
Select id, timestamp From dB as a
Join dB as b using (id)
Where a.timestamp BETWEEN a.timestamp AND b.timestamp - INTERVAL '1' minute
```

This let's me create 1 minute bins based on the start timestamp, but it doesn't solve adding the integer values of records that span the same duration which may have started earlier. Basically for any record that spans any given minute in a day I want to sum the the value of int1 and int 2

Comment: Hey Richard, I'm having trouble following this logic. Int 2 from record one seems to have no influence on your expected examples. Looks like both values from Record 2 are just getting doubles, or maybe sum of their Int 1's. Why is it back to the original values on 13:01:00.000, if it ends on 2023-12-01 13:00:00.000?

Comment: This logic might be subtle enough, or difficult to describe enough, that more than 2 example records are needed to make the pattern clear. If you format the input and output samples as markdown tables that is much easier on the eyes.

Comment: Noted, I'll add more example when I get to my computer tomorrow and hopefully articulate it better

Comment: A minute does NOT include the starting point of the next minute, the most accurate way to define a non-overlapping time period is to use >= with < e.g.`>= 2023-12-01 12:00:00.000 and < 2023-12-01 12:01:00.000`

Comment: @Error_2646, I added more details in the post.

Comment: @Richard Gotcha. Makes sense. And do you want this minute by or just for the minutes that are actually present as start or end times in your data?

Comment: @Error_2646 I'm trying to do this for every minute of every day, even if there are no overlapping values (those minutes would then be 0). However, the chances of never having values to sum in a single minute are just about NIL